# If a point has a path-connected neighborhood it also has an open path-connected neighborhood?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

If the answer is no: what does it happens if the space in wich lies the point is connected?

PS: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: By definition of a *neighbourhood*, I think it is already open.

Comment: Well, at least my definition is: a neighborhood of point is a set containing an open subset that contain the point, so no, it isn't already open...

Comment: I see. This definition is different from mine. But I love the answer below.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг. I have noticed that on this site the convention of "neighborhood" is the def'n in the comment  by Davide F. Also, on this site  $\mathbb N$ denotes the positive integers, i.e. $0\not \in \mathbb N,$ which I have reluctantly accepted.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Sorry for the late reply, but I suppose we can't do much about that. Conventions even depend upon where you have done your mathematical education, so occasionally when I do find contrasting notions and definitions, I feel the same way you do. In fact, up till now, whenever I have used $\mathbb N$, I have always specified that it contains zero. Most people on this site don't include it, the set with zero is called "whole numbers", I believe. So I suppose we can reluctantly accept some things. Which is fine for me, since everything else is fun on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a counterexample.  Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be the topologist's sine curve $\{0\}\times[-1,1]\cup\{(x,\sin(1/x)):0<x\leq 1\}$ and let $Y$ be an arc from $(0,-1)$ to $(1,\sin 1)$ that does not intersect $X$ except at the endpoints, so $X\cup Y$ is a [Warsaw circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_theory_(mathematics)#Warsaw_Circle).  Let $Z$ be an arc that oscillates and approaches a segment of $Y$, so the union of $Z$ and that segment is another topologist's sine curve, and consider the space $A=X\cup Y\cup Z$.

Note that $A$ is connected, since it is the union of the two connected sets $X\cup Y$ and $\overline{Z}$ which have nonempty intersection.  The point $(0,0)\in A$ has a path-connected neighborhood in $A$, namely the set $X\cup Y$.  But $(0,0)$ has no path-connected open neighborhood in $A$: it is easy to see a path-connected neighborhood of $A$ must contain all of $X\cup Y$, and therefore must intersect $Z$ if it is open, but no path in $A$ can have points in both $Z$ and $X\cup Y$.